# How to set multiple connection string in Nhibernate and how to maintain multiple sessions under single sessionFactory

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover

I want to use two connection strings of two different sql database but
my problem is **nhibernate** allows one connection string for one
session under one **sessionFactory**. If I want to use second
connection string for different session and also these two database
insert operations maintain under one transaction. So how it possible
using **nhibernate**.

Comment: You should use two session factories and transaction scopes. Why do you have that requirement of a single session factory? Otherwise see [there](/a/45129618/1178314) for a way to use a single session factory, but you really should consider using two.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are on the same sql server which it sounds like they are,
this is possible by specifying the schema in your mappings. No need for multiple sessions.

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
    Schema("MyOtherDatabase.dbo");
  }
}
```

This will get appended to your NHibernate queries wherever `Person` is referenced.

For old school hibernate style mapping see: **5.1.2. hibernate-mapping** in http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html